# Where are the texdocs for the built-in LaTeX document classes?

Tags: document-classes, texdoc, documentation

I can `texdoc` for the following classes:
`letter`
`slides`
`proc`

But, where are the `texdoc`s for the following built-in document classes?
`article`
`report`
`book`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard classes are all built from the source file `classes.dtx`. Therefore:

```
texdoc classes
```

But I'm afraid you might be disappointed by its contents; it's not really a user manual, simply documented source code.

Comment: Am I right in saying that `latex2e` is the one closest to a user manual for these classes?

Comment: Oh, I hadn't seen latex2e.pdf before! Yes, that's a great document.